# How to insert two item into a list fit width carousel of Slick?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, slick.js

I'm using Slick to create a user profile card like this:

[image]

I am having a problem when tried to add two `profile card` in the same line of a carousel using the Slick library.

I decided to create a class `container` and `container-fluid` to create width enough to contain two `profile card` but I don't know it can't.

And Slick can be responsive my profile card?

Currently, I must be fixed `width` and `height` of `profile card`. So, it becomes broken in mobile UI.

In my pen it shows like:

[image]

You can see my pen at here:

http://codepen.io/r0ysy0301/pen/xROzrB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="regular slider slick-slider">
```

Your html bootstrap structure is totally wrong. I can rewrite the code plz check it on my pen....

You can see solution in my pen at here:

http://codepen.io/inewton/pen/ObXaPO

Comment: Sorry. I don't have experience with front-end. Thanks @Amit Kumar.

Comment: Normally, when I create class `container-fluid` by Bootstrap, a width of this class is fullscreen. Why slick auto scale to small. I want to show this slide fullscreen. Thanks, @amitkurmar.

Comment: becoz of this class [ .slider {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 100px auto;
} ] you changed the width 50% to 100% for full width.

Comment: Thank you very much @Amitkumar.